# Удаление из базы данных Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Хочу удалить данные одной строки в БД.Программа выдает следующую ошибку
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "test1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM items WHERE Name=test test1 test2 11 test3 and Qty=1

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_NAME = "Cart1.DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + DBDescription.Cart.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        DBDescription.Cart._ID + " integer primary key, " +
                        DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                        DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_QTY + " TEXT, " +
                        DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_TOTAL + " TEXT, " +
                        DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_IMG_PATH + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Удаление:

```
public void deleteTitle(String name,int total)
    {
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DBDescription.Cart.TABLE_NAME,DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_NAME + "=" + name + " and " + DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_QTY + "=" + 1, null);
        db.close();
        myDbHelper.close();
    }
```

Comment: Ну так строки же в SQL в кавычках ... хотя посмотрите в вашем языке что нибудь про подготавливаемые запросы, что бы не вставлять текст в запрос явно, а использовать привязываемые параметры

Comment: если проверяю только по имени то выдает такую же ошибку. 
db.delete(DBDescription.Cart.TABLE_NAME,DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_NAME + "="+ name, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пробуй

```
db.delete(DBDescription.Cart.TABLE_NAME,DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\" and " + DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_QTY + "=" + 1, null);
```

или

```
db.delete(DBDescription.Cart.TABLE_NAME,DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_NAME + "= ? and " + DBDescription.Cart.COLUMN_QTY + "=" + 1, new String[]{name});
```